# login , remember me, application using java servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to implement a login(remember me) application, and i'm having a problem to manage the cookies. when i'm doing Register(for new members) or login(for members that already have been registered) i'm doing in the server:

```
Cookie returnVisitorCookie = new Cookie("repeatVisitor", "yes");
returnVisitorCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); // 1 year
response.addCookie(returnVisitorCookie);
```

where the response i'm getting from the browser. for example : visitor.login(response).

When i'm doing SIGNOUT, i'm deleting the cookie. but it's seems that i have more cookies 
that it should be, i mean if i registered 2 members and signout, i still have cookies with name = "repeatVisitor" and value = "yes".

Maybe because i'm putting the cookie in different respones.

Anybody can give me an idae what i'm doing wrong and how should i implement this?
Thank you

Comment: If you're setting this cookie, how can you register two users without logging out? It sounds like you're setting it multiple times before unsetting it, which shouldn't be possible - that would imply you're logging in when you're already logged in.

Comment: @PWhite even if you were logging in while already logged in, the above code would just overwrite the existing cookie.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Java deals with cookies, which is why I haven't posted an answer. I know that's true in other backend languages.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes find the best way to learn or understand is by looking at an example. Here is some code we use for a working website:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = {"/authorization/Login"})
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            System.out.println("Reached login");
            if (!Authorization.isLoggedIn(request)) {
                String login = request.getParameter("login");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                boolean remember = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("remember"));

                System.out.println("Reached login "+login+", "+password+","+remember);
                if (!Authorization.validateLogin(login, password)) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO,
                            "Failed login (invalid password) from {0} for {1}",
                            new String[]{request.getRemoteAddr(), login});
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid username or password!");
                    return;
                }
                //So far so good... Get the user object from the database (unique login names)
                DB_User user = DB_User.get(login);
                if (!user.getActive()) {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Your account is no longer active!");
                    return;
                }
                String sessionID = Authorization.createNewSession(user, request.getRemoteAddr(), remember);
                Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("my_application.session_id", sessionID);
                sessionCookie.setDomain(request.getServerName());
                sessionCookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
                if (remember) {
                    sessionCookie.setMaxAge(ServerConfig.getLoginSessionTimeout());
                }

                response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
            }
            response.sendRedirect("/app/myAccount.jsp");
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ServletUtils.handleException(ex, response);
        } finally {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // +HttpSerlet default methods here. (doGet, doPost, getServletInfo)
}
```

Logout servlet example:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Logout", urlPatterns = {"/authorization/Logout"})
public class Logout extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            String sessionID = ServletUtils.getCookieValue(request.getCookies(),"my_application.session_id");

            if (sessionID != null) {
                SQLManager sql = ServerConfig.getSql();
                sql.deleteFromTable("login_session", "session_id = " + SQLString.toSql(sessionID));

                Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("my_application.session_id", null);
                sessionCookie.setDomain(ServletUtils.getCookieDomain(request));
                sessionCookie.setPath("/you_app_name");
                sessionCookie.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
            }
            response.sendRedirect("/security/login.jsp");

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Logout.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ServletUtils.handleException(ex, response);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

There are some helper classes we have made as you will notice but the concept is there nonetheless. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You'll keep having the `repeatVisitor` cookie present in subsequent requests for at least a year, you've instructed the client's browser to do just that, "keep the cookie alive for a year". Removing the cookie from subsequent request headers won't stop a browser from simply re-adding it.

To implement remember me successfully, you need to

1. Use a secure token, not just a flag that says "repeat user : yes". Generate a unique token using something like [java's UUID class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) to uniquely identify a visitor securely, so someone just doesn't intercept a request and put something in the header for you to deal with
2. **Actively** manage the secure token you generated per user. That means you store the token you generated in some persistent storage and check repeat requests against this store. It is within this store that you will manage token expiry and so forth. So in your persistent store, you can flag the token as inactive or expired

As an alternative, the easier remember me route is to set your remember-me to a fixed time duration for which you'll now set the cookie expiry date in the `HttpServletRequest` object. That is, you'll have your check box saying `remember me for 2 weeks` and then set your cookie expiry to 2 weeks. Subsequent representments of the same cookie token will be automatically managed without stress.